# Accessing Form variable from outside of a method

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

```
public class Simple : Form
{
    public Simple()
    {
        Text = "Server Command Line";
        Size = new Size(800, 400);
        CenterToScreen();
        Button button = new Button();
        TextBox txt = new TextBox ();
        txt.Location = new Point (20, Size.Height - 70);
        txt.Size = new Size (600, 30);
        txt.Parent = this;
        txt.KeyDown += submit;
        button.Text = "SEND";
        button.Size = new Size (50, 20);
        button.Location = new Point(620, Size.Height-70);
        button.Parent = this;
        button.Click += new EventHandler(sSubmit);   
    }

    private void submit(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter ) {
            Console.WriteLine ("txt.Text");//How do I grab this?
            Submit();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to access `txt.Text` from outside the Form, and google hasn't been helpful either. How do I access it?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine()` in a winform?

Comment: See this msdn link for more information on variable scope http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

Comment: @Precious1tj quite common for troubleshooting purposes actually.

Comment: @Ralph Ok. i just been using winforms for about 2 months now and of all the books i've read. I've never really seen anything like that

Answer (score 1):

Your txt variable is declared within the local scope of the Simple() constructor.  You will not be able to access it anywhere outside of this scope like you are doing in your submit method.

What you may want to do is create a private instance variable within your Simple class that you will then be able to access from any method declared that belongs to this class.

Example:

```
public class Simple : Form
{
    //now this is field is accessible from any method of declared within this class
    private TextBox _txt;
    public Simple()
    {
        Text = "Server Command Line";
        Size = new Size(800, 400);
        CenterToScreen();
        Button button = new Button();
        _txt = new TextBox ();
        _txt.Location = new Point (20, Size.Height - 70);
        _txt.Size = new Size (600, 30);
        _txt.Parent = this;
        _txt.KeyDown += submit;
        button.Text = "SEND";
        button.Size = new Size (50, 20);
        button.Location = new Point(620, Size.Height-70);
        button.Parent = this;
        button.Click += new EventHandler(sSubmit);   
}

private void submit(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter ) {
        Console.WriteLine (_txt.Text);//How do I grab this?
        Submit ();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You have to define some variable `txt` of `TextBox` somewhere in your form class, this is in fact done automatically by designer for you when you drag-n-drop a `TextBox` from `Toolbox` onto your form. This variable is an instance of `TextBox`. It should be initialized using the constructor `TextBox()` and with some properties as you did in your code. You can use this variable in the scope of the form class `Simple`. It has property `Text` (of type `string`) which can be modified or fetched to display. To access a property, just use this pattern: `[instance Name].[Property name]`

```
public class Simple : Form
{
  public Simple()
  {
    Text = "Server Command Line";
    Size = new Size(800, 400);
    CenterToScreen();
    Button button = new Button();
    txt = new TextBox ();
    txt.Location = new Point (20, Size.Height - 70);
    txt.Size = new Size (600, 30);
    txt.Parent = this;
    txt.KeyDown += submit;
    button.Text = "SEND";
    button.Size = new Size (50, 20);
    button.Location = new Point(620, Size.Height-70);
    button.Parent = this;
    button.Click += new EventHandler(sSubmit);   
  }
  TextBox txt;
  private void submit(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter ) {
        Console.WriteLine (txt.Text);
        Submit();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you did for him so it's plain to see? :P

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun added some very basic explanation, I don't think this should be added. The OP should read some very basic book on `class` and `winforms` first.

Comment: @KingKing That may be, but a block of code with no explanation or context of what you are trying to show the OP is IMHO counter productive.

Answer (score 0):

By default (and for good reason) controls created on forms using the designer are private.  You could change it to public, but a better solution would be to just create a public property on the Form to expose it.

```
public string MyTextField { get { return txt.Text; } }
```

Of course you could also add a setter in there too if you want to change it from the outside.  However, keep in mind that if you are trying to access controls on a thread other then the one they were created on you will have a separate cross-threading concern to deal with, but there are plenty of posts on how to deal with that issue on SO already.